# Best way to store different values in pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble to figure out the best or easiest way to store multiple data about the same entity in a pandas column, to exemplify, i have some pandas dataframes that looks like this:

```
                a    b     c
     item0    2.0  NaN   1.1
     item1    1.3  2.2   2.0
     item2    1.4  NaN   NaN

                a    b     c
     item0    foo  bar   bar
     item1    bar  foo   bar
     item2    foo  foo   bar
```

I would like to aggregate these dataframes values into one, I'm not being successful in trying to assign them to a multi index dataframe, this is what I'm hoping to get:

```
                                   a                        b                         c
     item0    {prop1:2.0, prop2: foo}  {prop1:NaN, prop2: bar}   {prop1:1.1, prop2: bar}
     item1    {prop1:1.3, prop2: bar}  {prop1:2.2, prop2: foo}   {prop1:2.0, prop2: bar}
     item2    {prop1:1.4, prop2: foo}  {prop1:NaN, prop2: foo}   {prop1:NaN, prop2: bar}
```

Or

```
                         a              b              c
              prop1  prop2   prop1  prop2   prop1  prop2
     item0      2.0    foo     NaN    bar     1.1    bar
     item1      1.3    bar     2.2    foo     2.0    bar
     item2      1.4    foo     NaN    foo     NaN    bar
```

Is there a simple way to aggregate multiple dataframes in these forms?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SamAct I've tried creating a dataframe in which each cell would be a dict, with no luck because pandas tries to parse it. Also tried creating a multi index dataframe to store the values but when i make `mult_df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'prop1']] = df1` the values are not updated, I'm not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [2., 1.3, 1.4], 'b': [np.nan, 2.2, np.nan], 'c': [1.1, 2., np.nan]},
     index=['item0', 'item1', 'item2']
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'b': ['bar', 'foo', 'foo'], 'c': ['bar'] * 3},
     index=['item0', 'item1', 'item2']
)


df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1, ['prop1']])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2, ['prop2']])

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
          a           b           c      
      prop1 prop2 prop1 prop2 prop1 prop2
item0   2.0   foo   NaN   bar   1.1   bar
item1   1.3   bar   2.2   foo   2.0   bar
item2   1.4   foo   NaN   foo   NaN   bar
```

Alternatively, concatenate the dataframes (assuming that they have identical columns), assign a new multi-index, then resort back to the original order:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(product(['prop1', 'prop2'], df1))
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)[product(df1, ['prop1', 'prop2'])]
```

Or per the `keys` parameter as used by @ALollz:

```
keys = ['prop1', 'prop2']
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=keys)
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)[product(df1, keys)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The second option is preferable. You lose much of the `pandas` efficiency when you store objects in a DataFrame like dictionaries. Also basic manipulations become more difficult.

Since the alignment is on the Index, this is just `concat` with the `keys` argument. You can then swap the levels if you want `prop` on the bottom.

```
res = (pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['prop1', 'prop2'])
         .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1))

print(res)
          a           b           c      
      prop1 prop2 prop1 prop2 prop1 prop2
item0   2.0   foo   NaN   bar   1.1   bar
item1   1.3   bar   2.2   foo   2.0   bar
item2   1.4   foo   NaN   foo   NaN   bar
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way to aggregate multiple dataframes in these forms?

As I understand you question, you are trying to figure out which index to use for the aggregation or merging of multiple DataFrames.

`Pandas` offers three ways, `concat()`, `merge()`, `join()`

You need to specify the index, Left, Inner, Right.
[image]

Src: [Merge DF](https://datacarpentry.org/python-ecology-lesson/05-merging-data/)

If this seems like what you are looking for, I can extend on this answer.